# XcodeでUILabelがセグエ出来ません。

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcodeを使ってobjective-cでカウントアプリを作っています。
ボタンとラベルのみのシンプルなもので、UILabelを入力してラベルとつなげようとしたら○が出てこなくて文字の色も黒のままでした。
スペルミスなどもなかったです。
これは設定の問題とかなのでしょうか？
初めて開発しているので分かりやすい回答をお願いします。

Comment: UILabelにIBOutletを付けていますか?

Comment: >ura14h さん
IBOutletをつけていますが出来ませんでした。
IBOutletの部分だけちゃんとピンク色になりました。

Comment: ビューコントローラのクラス名はStoryboard/XIBとObjective-Cとで同じ名前になっていますか？(規定ではViewControllerというクラス名になっているはずです)

Answer (score 1):

Outletを最初から書いて繋ぐのではなく、UI部品をソースの行間に右クリックで引っ張ってきてみて下さい。青い「ここに行が挿入されるよ」っていう線が出ますので、その状態でマウスから手を放します。
すると、どんな型で、どんな名前のOutletにするかダイアログが出ますので、そこにOutlet名を入力します。

これはIBActionでも有効ですのでお試し下さい。